# @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class) but Spring still starts Hibernate stuff, how to fix this?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
```

in my code, but Spring still starts Hibernate stuff, how to fix this without full excluding of DataSourceAutoConfiguration?

Spring boot 2.2.0.RELEASE.

```
[DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.494 [main] TraversableResolvers - Found javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath containing 'getPersistenceUtil'. Assuming JPA 2 environment. Trying to instantiate JPA aware TraversableResolver
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.495 [main] TraversableResolvers - Instantiated JPA aware TraversableResolver of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.495 [main] ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator - Loaded expression factory via original TCCL
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.497 [main] TraversableResolvers - Found javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath containing 'getPersistenceUtil'. Assuming JPA 2 environment. Trying to instantiate JPA aware TraversableResolver
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.497 [main] TraversableResolvers - Instantiated JPA aware TraversableResolver of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.498 [main] ConfigurationImpl - Setting custom MessageInterpolator of type org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.499 [main] ConfigurationImpl - Setting custom ConstraintValidatorFactory of type org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringConstraintValidatorFactory
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.499 [main] ConfigurationImpl - Setting custom ParameterNameProvider of type org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean$1
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.501 [main] ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.501 [main] ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via user class loader
[DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.501 [main] ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.502 [main] ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.502 [main] ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.509 [main] ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator as ValidatorFactory-scoped message interpolator.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.509 [main] ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver as ValidatorFactory-scoped traversable resolver.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.510 [main] ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped parameter name provider.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.510 [main] ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultClockProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped clock provider.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.510 [main] ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.620 [main] TraversableResolvers - Found javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath containing 'getPersistenceUtil'. Assuming JPA 2 environment. Trying to instantiate JPA aware TraversableResolver
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.620 [main] TraversableResolvers - Instantiated JPA aware TraversableResolver of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.620 [main] ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator - Loaded expression factory via original TCCL
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.620 [main] ConfigurationImpl - Setting custom MessageInterpolator of type org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.621 [main] ConfigurationImpl - Setting custom ConstraintValidatorFactory of type org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringConstraintValidatorFactory
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.621 [main] ConfigurationImpl - Setting custom ParameterNameProvider of type org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean$1
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.621 [main] ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.621 [main] ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via user class loader
[DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.621 [main] ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.622 [main] ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.622 [main] ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.628 [main] ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator as ValidatorFactory-scoped message interpolator.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.628 [main] ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver as ValidatorFactory-scoped traversable resolver.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.628 [main] ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped parameter name provider.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.628 [main] ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultClockProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped clock provider.
        [DEBUG] 2019-11-14 19:01:17.628 [main] ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
    exclude = {
      DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
      DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
      HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
    })
```

Comment: without full excluding of DataSourceAutoConfiguration, but thnx

Answer (score 1):

The log messages are all related to Hibernate Validator rather than Hibernate (the ORM). Even the messages that mention `javax.persistence` and JPA are from Hibernate Validator as it does some work to detect what sort of environment it is running in.

Comment: thnaks! Is it possible to disable it?